# How to unindent while taking care of expandtab and tabstop in Vim

Tags: vim, indentation

I've set the expandtab and tabstop=4 in Vim. So, when I press tab, it indents by adding two spaces. Now I'd like to do the behavior in reverse, i.e. minus two spaces, I don't know how to do it. If I press <<, it minuses 8 spaces. shift + tab does nothing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>>` and `<<` widths are controlled by the `shiftwidth`/`sw` option. You can set it to 0 in order for it to use the same value as `tabstop`/`ts` option.